# Spring Security 3.1 ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider returning partial result exception

Tags: active-directory, spring-security

I am trying to authenticate users to an Active Directory Instance using spring security, I am getting an Partial Results Exception. I am going around in circles trying to figure this out. Below is my config.

security-app-context

```xml
<authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin@damien.com" authorities="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" password="123admin123" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="myDomain.com" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://ldapurl:389/" />
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Error I am getting

```
 org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0        org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:239)
```

I am struggling to find examples and the documentation indicates I am working in the right direction.

This is from the logs

```
SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java 213 - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=myDomain,dc=com', filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))'
```

and this is what I would expect that to look like on a successful attempt from some scripts that work

```
Searching for entry under DN 'OU=Users and Groups,DC=one,DC=two,DC=myDomain,DC=com', base = 'OU=Users and Groups,DC=one,DC=two,DC=myDomain,DC=com', filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))'
```

Do I need to get the DN populated? How? I have looked through the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider properties and don't see a way? Also the base is off but myDomain.com is the correct domain for users e.g john.doe@myDomain.com. Has anyone come across a similar problem?

Comment: Is the filter actually valid for the user in question? If not, you may be experiencing the problem reported [in this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1915).

Comment: Hi Luke, The user filter is valid but the base is less specific and the DN has not been set.From trying to use an ldapsearch command line tool with the spring values(no DN,less specific base but with user to bind and search) I get an error, but when I specify full base with an  "OU=" value I get a successful return. I have read that referrals can cause issues with active directory, maybe this is the problem. In the meantime I am going to look at the other authentication-provider's or write my own if none work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Luke Taylor I have used a ldap-authentication-provider with the user-search-base defined which works. I'm not sure why the ActiveDirectory Authenticator would not work but I'm guessing it was to do with referrals as when the search base was narrowed it returned successfully.

Comment: Could you paste the complete code including the configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I used the default LDAP provider which enables user search base to be specified, specifying the user search base and user search filter.

```xml
<ldap-authentication-provider
    user-search-base="OU=Users and Groups,DC=abc,DC=myDomain,DC=com"
    user-search-filter="userPrincipalName={0}" />
```

A user would then be logging in with john.doe@myDomain.com but the usersearch base is more specific(abc.myDomain.com). I believe AD Spring was falling down due to this.